# iPhone + download videos

Tags: iphone, video, download

How to create an application, that will allow users to download videos to their iPhone from some server.

Comment: The question you're asking is too broad.  Pick an aspect of this application and ask about that.  We're not going to write your program for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's [HTTP Live Streaming Overview](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide).

Comment: hi Jeff, i dont want live streaming, its like there will be video uploaded on some server and user can download the video whenever they want and save into their iPhone

Comment: Or take in other way, how can I download a file from any server and store in my iPhone.

Comment: Yeah, what everyone else said. There are a million ways to do this. I'd recommend getting a book on iPhone development, reading it, and then trying to do this when you have a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty general question.  Basically you can just download it to application documents directory and play it from there.